# send a variable with a value to front end of all routes node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have `req.session` values that are being stored upon login. But what I want to do is access them on every page of my app (front-end(ejs)), but i don't want to go into every single route/function i have and pass it. So i was wondering if there is a universal way to pass `req.session` to the front-end from one route and access them on all pages?

my routes look like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render("index.ejs");
})
```

sorry if this is an odd question, but wondering if there is universal ways to do things like this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? Why dont you just store it in the frontend after a successfull login?

Comment: Sounds like you need some middleware
` // a middleware function with no mount path. This code is executed for every request to the router
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
}) 
`

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @DeadApe not sure how to do that. How would I go about storing in the front-end?

Comment: LocalStorage and SessionStorage are APIs you can use to store data in the frontend. I'm assuming you want to store this after a successful login to avoid repeat attempts. If so then you may want to alter your application login logic such that it first checks if an unexpired session is in storage. If not then it logs in and stores the session id with some time to live value (which indicates when the session expires).

Answer (score 0):

In authentication, you probably need these two things:

- Front end: Context to form a global state around authentication information
- Back end: Retrieve user info based on session id sent & Middleware to authenticate the requests

You should set up something like `authContext` to fetch information of sessionID from backend, and trigger some function on login and logout to revise the authentication. You may want to research React Context to figure out how to apply "global state", if you are not familiar with that.

In the backend, use middleware to authenticate every HTTP request and apply that middleware to the route you want to apply authentication.

Which can go something like this:

```
async function auth (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const session = await MySessions.findById(req.sessionID);
    if (!session) throw 'Not authenticated'
    else next()
  } catch (error) {
    // Response will be rejected, and wont be passed to route due to not sending next()
    return res.status(401).send({ error })
  }
}

// Example of applying middleware auth to route you need.
router.delete('/:postId', auth, async (req, res) => { ... }
```